# FireDAC Dataset.Recno not working properly, show the first and Last record row number as 0

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a problem which I can not figure out a cause for it?
I use OnCalcl event of a TFDQuery to set the Record Number in the DBGrid for every record by the corresponding Recno property.
it seems that the dataset.recno has a bug? it always shows First record no. = 0
and if records are more than (say 40), also the last record No. = 0
but the remining records No. are correct in the TDBGrid, So Why this?

To let you recreate the issue, First you may create a simple SQLIte database named [SQLiteTestDB.db] as follow:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Table1";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Table1" (
"ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
"EmployeeName"  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT));
COMMIT;
```

then we create this Delphi VCL Form Program which contain only one form and within it a TDBGrid ,
Note: I change nothing in the properties value of any FireDAC component, all are the same default properties for FDConnection and FDQuery.
the code is as follow:

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def,
  FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat,
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef, Data.DB, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids,
  FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
    FDQuery1RecordNumberField: TIntegerField;
    FDQuery1ID: TIntegerField;
    FDQuery1EmployeeName: TStringField;
    procedure FDQuery1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Procedure InserDummyData;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FDQuery1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
FDQuery1RecordNumberField.AsInteger := FDQuery1.RecNo;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDConnection1.close;
  // we put the Database file in the application directory
  FDConnection1.Params.Database := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'SQLiteTestDB.db';
  FDConnection1.Params.DriverID :='SQLite';
  FDConnection1.open;
  InserDummyData;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text:='Select * From Table1';
  FDQuery1.open;
end;

procedure TForm1.InserDummyData;
var i : integer;
begin
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('Delete from Table1');
  for I := 1 to 10 do
  begin
     FDConnection1.ExecSQL('Insert into Table1(EmployeeName) VALUES(''an employee Name'');');
  end;
end;

end.
```

The result was as follow:

[image]

then if we change the max value for the dummy data in procedure.InserDummyData
to, say (40) instead for (10) then the First and Last recno will be Zeros.
Why this?

The strange thing is that :
when we navigate through records in the DBGrid by the scroll bar it reproduce the issue, but when I use the mouse wheel it shows the correct recno for the first and last record!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the fetch mode to fetch all rows? [Fetching Rows](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Fetching_Rows_(FireDAC))

Comment: Yes, I tried every thing before, set fetch to all , fetch Mode to fmAll, AutofetchAll to afAll, RecordCountMode to cmTotal  but same problem.

Comment: Note: the Problem is solved if I use ClientDataset instead to FDQuery as a dataset to feed the Data Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the recordcountmode to **cmTotal**